# Multiple pipelines in AWK

Tags: awk, pipeline

I want to do something like this:

```
'{ 
    var = "value";
    "echo -n "$var"|"xxd -r -p"|"sha256sum"|"cut -d \" \" -f 1"|getline var;
}'
```

I guess in awk I can't use piplines this way, so how can this be implemented in awk?

Comment: You can use `system` to run shell commands from Awk; but this seems like a case where perhaps you should switch to a third language entirely. What you are asking would be easy to do natively in Python, for example.

Comment: `echo -n` behavior is implementation defined in `sh` so it's safer to use `printf` for system calls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
'{ 
    var = "value"
    cmd = "echo -n \047" var "\047 | xxd -r -p | sha256sum | cut -d \" \" -f 1"
    var = ( (cmd | getline line) > 0 ? line : "Failed: " var )
    close(cmd)
    print var
}'
```

but it's extremely unlikely that this is the best way to do whatever it is you're trying to do. I'm setting `var` to `"Failed: " var` if the pipeline to getline fails, you'll have to decide how you really want to handle it. See http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline for when/how to use `getline` and it's many caveats.

Comment: Also, the quoting will fail if `value` contains a literal quote character.

Comment: As mentioned `it's extremely unlikely that this is the best way to do whatever it is you're trying to do`, I'm just answer the OPs question about how to implement that pipeline in awk.

Answer (score 0):

*tested and confirmed working on `mawk`, `gawk`, and `nawk`*

=

```
 <( … input_from_/dev/stdin … )> |

 mawk '
 function ______(__,_) {
 1     _ = "\47"
 1     gsub(_, "&\\" (_)_,__)

 1     return (_)(__)_
   }

 function _______(__,_,___) {
 1     return \
       substr( (___ = RS)*(RS = "\n"), 
        (_=" printf \47%s\47 " (______(__))" | xxd -p " \
           " | xxd -p -r | xxh128sum | awk NF=1") | getline __, 
                           \
       close(_)*_*(RS = ___))__
 }

 {
 1     print $+(_="")

 1     printf("\n xxhash-128-from-_INPUT_ :: ")

 1     printf("%s", $-_) | (__="xxh128sum ")
 1                    close(__)

 1     _ = _______($-_)

 1     print "\n xxhash-128-from-getline "\
                       ":: getline :: [[ "(_)" ]]\n" } '
```

> —- it's one-single line, but reformatted for readability

```
The quick brown fox !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>
?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnop
qrstuvwxyz{|}~jumps over the lazy !"#$%&'()*+,-./0
123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`ab
cdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~dog

 xxhash-128-from-_INPUT_ :: 5a43bf3eab449ca21b817f0baeee2a4b  stdin

 xxhash-128-from-getline :: getline :: [[ 5a43bf3eab449ca21b817f0baeee2a4b ]]
```